# How to disable the button in the form until the user fill the important fields

Tags: java, android

i have Form that the user will fill it, 
But, i have some field that the user should fill it : 
-case name
-CaseAge
-CaseDurationH, CaseDurationM (it is for time)
-GenderSelection
then the user also should fill CasePic or CaseClothes
if the user fill these 5 important fields then the Next button will be enabled otherwise it will be disabled.

and this is My code, but it is not complete, because i do not hava any idea how to complete it!

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText edit1;
EditText edit2;
EditText edit3;
Button button;
String test1;
 RadioGroup GenderSelection;
 Spinner CaseDurationH, CaseDurationM;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Your initialization code...
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            edit1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
            edit2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
            GenderSelection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            CaseDurationH = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Shr);
            CaseDurationM = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Smin);


   TextWatcher watcher = new LocalTextWatcher();
    edit1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    edit2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    //radiogroup();
    int id = GenderSelection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    if (id == -1){
        //no item selected
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
        if (id == R.id.radio0){
            //Do something with the button
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }  else{
            if (id == R.id.radio1){
                //Do something with the button
                button.setEnabled(true);
            } else{
                if (id == R.id.radio2){
                    //Do something with the button
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }

    updateButtonState();}}}
}

void updateButtonState() {
    boolean enabled;
    if(checkEditText(edit1) && checkEditText(edit2)) button.setEnabled(false);
    else button.setEnabled(true);
        }

private boolean checkEditText(EditText edit) {
    return edit.getText().length() == 0;
}

      private class LocalTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        updateButtonState();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }}}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing?  Your logic looks sound (though not complete), but you have issues of not initializing some objects before you use them...is this your issue?

Comment: my issue is i know how to `addTextChangedListener(watcher)` to the text but how can i do it for other type ? like ImageView,Spinner,RadioGroup, also how to put the code that let the user fill CasePic or CaseClothes

Comment: You should edit your question and put that in at the bottom.  Because the way your question is currently worded, it is hard to tell what your issue is.

Comment: should i put the whole class ?

Comment: You should put a proper question.

Comment: thank you in advance and i am sorry if you see my question not proper for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Most `View` classes support 'event listeners', classes that are called back upon when a certain event occurs (with Android, these are often when a user does something).

For `RadioGroup`, one such method would be [`RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).  You can set your `OnCheckedChangeListener` onto your `RadioGroup` via the [`setOnCheckedChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) method of `RadioGroup`.  This method is similar to the `addTextChangedListener()` (another listener) method that you are currently using for your `TextView`'s.

I would recommend taking a look at the [Android JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), which has all of this information available for you.

Comment: i try with RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener but it is give me an error :(

Comment: Without knowing the error, it is nearly impossible to help.  This is important information that you should put in your question.

Comment: ok i am sorry i did not mention that :$ please be patient with me, i am really sorry if i bothering you, the error is :The method OnCheckedChangeListener(TextWatcher) is undefined for the type RadioGroup

Comment: please help me, really i am stuck here since yesterday

Comment: You need to implement a different interface for the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method to work.

Comment: What about it?  What did you change?  Does it work? Is there a stacktrace that suggests something is wrong?

Comment: 1- my code it is not complete, i do not know how to check if the user insert some value in spinner or not.2-i put code to check if the user choose in the radio group or not,but it did not work. thank you